# How to change layout of a transposed dataframe using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-requests, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to change the layout of a payload of data from pandas to a different format. I know this has most likely been answered but I am confused on the terminology to search.

```
params = {
        'count':10,
        'position':'contained'}

url = requests.get('https://apitest.com/api/models',auth=('', ''),params=params)
r = json.loads(url.content)

i = r['items']
d = []

for h in i:
    d.append(
            { 'Name': h['name'],
              'RoomName': h['room']['name'],
              'DateLastScanned':h['dateLastScanned']
                        } 
            )

pd.DataFrame(d, columns= ['Name','RoomName','DateLastScanned'])
```

From this point I get my desired layout and its able to be rendered in Juypter Notebook 
[Which is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5e00.png)
I want to be able to use unique and max commands on the dataframe so I take the next step to transpose

```
df =pd.DataFrame(d).transpose()
display(df)
```

and it changes  to this format [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4uIa.png)

How would I change the tranposed dataframe to the initial display layout format in the first screenshot. Any help or guidance  would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try `df = df.T`

Comment: looks like you need to use the  'transpose' method one more time, so the ans given by @dimitris_ps or `df = df.transpose()` should work fine.

Comment: Thank you both! This has worked for me. I am still learning and appreciate the help. I do not know  how to accept this as the answer @PRIN

Comment: Glad these answers worked for you. You could simply 'vpvote' these comments if you like using the triangular button (just above the flag)